# How to convert xls or xlsx to XML spreadsheet 2003 using C#

Tags: c#, xlsx, xls, xml-spreadsheet

How to convert xls or xlsx to XML spreadsheet 2003 using C#?
I know Spire.XLS does provide such functionality 
https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/excel-for-net-introduce.html
Is there any better way to do it?
I will be having a bulk of xls or xlsx dumped in to a folder which I need to convert it to XML spreadsheet.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: `FileFormat` 46 is `xlXMLSpreadsheet` - Have you tried this yet?  Please show your attempt so far at saving standard Excel Workbooks as "XML Spreadsheets" so we clearly understand what you're attempting to do.  See [here for the `FileFormat` breakdowns available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)

Comment: You can just do a SaveAs *.XLM in Excel.  Or read query the Excel using OLEDB and save into a DataTable.  Then use the DataTable WriteXml method.